# How to connect to client in GCE in GO

Tags: go, google-compute-engine

I can't able to connect to client. Is there any way to pass `private key id` and `private key` to client for get authorized?

So, far i see:

```
ctx := context.Background()

client, err := google.DefaultClient(ctx, compute.ComputeScope)
    if err != nil {
            //...
    }
computeService, err := compute.New(client)
    if err != nil {
            //...
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, Need to create a credential for service account in GCE and it will download a json file and it will use for authorize the client.

```
Sample Code :

data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("downloadedfile.json")
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}
conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(data, compute.ComputeScope) // give the specific permission for this client.
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
client = conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext)

computeService, err := compute.New(client)
if err != nil {
        //...
}
```